# Why I can not input value to inout type?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, xilinx-ise

- I create this code from this curcuit [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjgzw.png)
- And this is Error image [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9UzC.png)
- This curcuit is Quadruple Bus Transcievers with 3-state outputs

**Verilog Code**

```
module Q52QuadrupleBus3Stlate(GAB,GBA,A,B);
    inout [3:0] A,B;
    input GAB,GBA;
    reg winA,winB;
    assign  B = (GAB==1&&GBA==0) ? winA : 4'hz;
    assign  A = (GAB==0&&GBA==1) ? winB : 4'hz;
    always @ (GAB or GBA)
    begin
        winA <= A;
        winB <= B;
    end
endmodule
```

**Test Bench**

```
`timescale 1ps / 1ps
module Q52TestBench;
    reg GAB;
    reg GBA;
    // Bidirs
    wire [3:0] A;
    wire [3:0] B;
    parameter step = 10000;
    Q52QuadrupleBus3Stlate uut (GAB,GBA,A,B);
    initial begin
            GAB = 0;
            GBA = 0;
            A = 0; B = 0;
    #step GAB = 1;
    #step GBA = 0;
    #step GAB = 0;
    #step GBA = 1;
    #step GAB = 1;
    #step GBA = 0;
    #step GAB = 0;
    #step GBA = 1;
    #(step*10) $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: You can not drive wire from procedural blocks. You need something like: `reg A1; assign A = (some_condition) ? A1 : 'hz;` and drive `A1` from procedural block.

Comment: Thx very much. verilog so difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Verilog:

- a `wire` must be driven by the `output` (or `inout`) of an instantiated module or an `assign` statement
- a `reg` must be driven by an `always` or `initial` block.

The decision as to whether a signal is to be a reg or a wire is driven primarily by what kind of code is driving the signal. Your signals `A` and `B` are driven by both the output of an instantiated module (`uut`) and by an `initial` block. So, you have a dilemma. Fortunately, there is a simple solution to this, which is commonly used in Verilog.

To drive an `inout` from an `initial` or `always` block, you need some extra signals in addition to the wires connected to your module `inout` ports (`A` and `B` in your case). You need a `reg` to correspond with each:

```
reg  [3:0] Ain;
reg  [3:0] Bin;
```

and an enable signal to correspond with each:

```
reg        Aen;
reg        Ben;
```

Then you need to implement some tri-state drivers using `assign` statements:

```
assign A = Aen ? Ain : 'bz;
assign B = Ben ? Bin : 'bz;
```

You need to drive the `reg`s from the `initial` block, not the `wire`s:

```
        Ain = 0; Bin = 0;
```

and finally, you also need to drive the enable signals from the same `initial` block:

```
        Aen = 1; Ben = 1;
```

Here's the complete code:

```
`timescale 1ps / 1ps
module Q52TestBench;
    reg GAB;
    reg GBA;
    // Bidirs
    wire [3:0] A;
    wire [3:0] B;
    reg  [3:0] Ain;
    reg  [3:0] Bin;
    reg        Aen;
    reg        Ben;
    parameter step = 10000;
    Q52QuadrupleBus3Stlate uut (GAB,GBA,A,B);
    assign A = Aen ? Ain : 'bz;
    assign B = Ben ? Bin : 'bz;
    initial begin
            GAB = 0;
            GBA = 0;
            Ain = 0; Bin = 0;
            Aen = 1; Ben = 1;
    #step GAB = 1;
    #step GBA = 0;
    #step GAB = 0;
    #step GBA = 1;
    #step GAB = 1;
    #step GBA = 0;
    #step GAB = 0;
    #step GBA = 1;
    #(step*10) $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5biz