# Assign reg which has initial value

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, vivado

I'm implementing a tetris game using basys 3 on 8x8 led matrix.

```
reg [7:0]redBlock;
reg [7:0]backupRed= 8'b00011000;
reg [7:0]temp;

assign redBlock=(toRight& oe) ? backupRed>> 1 : backupRed;
```

This code is working the redblock on led matrix goes right when I push button toRight but of couse it goes back to it's initial position since the condition 0 is equal to backupRed

What I really want is

```
reg [7:0]redBlock = 8'b00011000;;
reg [7:0]backupRed;
reg [7:0]temp;

assign redBlock=(toRight& oe) ? redBlock>> 1 : redBlock;
```

which should update the previous location of redBlock but it gives error

> Variable redBlcok is written by both continuous and procedural assigments

I'm using Vivado for implemantion

Here is 10sec video of what I meant

http://sendvid.com/ei5bfqc3

Comment: See answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527671/when-should-i-use-reg-instead-of-wire/36527832#36527832) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344169/why-i-can-not-input-value-to-inout-type/39345924#39345924).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an continuous assignment `assign` to describe data that you wish to be stored.

Continuous assignments are used to describe combinatorical logic, but what you want here is sequential logic, a register (flip-flop).

Something along these lines:

```
reg [7:0]redBlock = 8'b00011000;

always @(posedge ck or posedge rst) begin
  if(rst)
    redBlock <= 8'b00011000;
  else
    redBlock <= (toRight& oe) ? redBlock>> 1 : redBlock;
end
```

Edit: Some thoughts on what kind of troubles you may run into.

Not sure what kind of signal `toRight`is, assuming that `toRight` is the raw button input:

Firstly, you need to [synchronize](http://www.edn.com/electronics-blogs/day-in-the-life-of-a-chip-designer/4435339/Synchronizer-techniques-for-multi-clock-domain-SoCs) your button input.

If your clock is slow in relation to the duration of `toRight`, you may need to capture the short pulse and generate a clock cycle long pulse.

If your clock is fast in relation to the duration of `toRight`, you may need to add a counter which can ensure that a single press of the button doesn't increment `redBlock` too much per press.

Furthermore you may need to handle the case where `redBlock` has reached the edge of your display.